# Какие кодеки используются на ютуб?

Tags: аудио, видео, youtube

Добрый день. Совсем не разбираюсь в аудио/видео кодеках, но, скачивал некоторые видео с ютуб и заметил, что при относительно хорошем качестве, видео в 720p на ютубе имеет довольно маленький размер. Возможно кто-то подскажет какие кодеки/настройки используются на ютубе для сжатия? Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VP9 - видео, AAC-LC - аудио, частота кадров - 30 или 60.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Попробую использовать.

Comment: https://blogs.gnome.org/rbultje/2015/09/28/vp9-encodingdecoding-performance-vs-hevch-264/ вот Вам ещё небольшая сравнительная характеристика P.S. забыл уточнить, что аппаратная реализация появилась у процессоров Intel только в 7 поколении